# Property grid visibility does not change in run-time c#

Tags: c#, runtime, propertygrid

I have three different property grids. These property grids may be visible or hidden based on the different scenarios. In some scenarios all property grids become visible and the height of them must be changed. In order to change the size of each property grid, I should check that which property grid is visible. but there is something strange. when I set the property grid visibility true and the debugger goes to the next line the value of the visibility is still false. 
the picture of the problem is shown as follow:
[image]

and this is the getter:
[image]

Comment: I cani only guess. You tell that you handle visibility of three grid. It may be you have some events triggered on the visibility changed of your grids. Is there in the handler of the event some that reset the valute of visibility of your grid?

Comment: @AlessandroCiurlo I use F10 it goes to the next line of the running code. if the next line is in the events then the pointer shows. I also double check this issue and search in the whole project. no there are not events to change this visibility. the amazing thing is although the size of the property grid is not going to change I can see in different scenario the property grids get visible and hidden in the application. I just think maybe the problem is in debug mode